# Meteor: display document's key and value without knowing the document itself?

Tags: meteor

I find that when I am iterating over a Meteor cursor, I don't know how I can display all document fields without knowing exactly how many fields there are or what they are called.

Essentially what I'd like to do is something like `print_r()` but it displays the document simply as the string of the key name and the data associated with it.

```
<template name="list">
    Requests:
    {{#each quotes}}
    {{key}} : {{value}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Underscore.js you could loop through the unknown document and add the values/keys to an array. Using this array in the template will let you output all the keys/values.

Like this (untested but should work):

```
// Template js
Template.whatever.elementToReturn = function() {
    var elementToReturn = [];
    var someDoc = CollectionWithUnknowFields.findOne({});
    var index = 0;
    _(someDoc).each( function( value, key, someDoc ) {
        elementToReturn[index] = {};
        elementToReturn[index]['value'] = value;
        elementToReturn[index]['key'] = key;
        index++;
    });
    return elementToReturn;
};

// Template HTML
<template name="whatever">

    {{#each elementToReturn}}

        <p>Key is: {{key}}</p>
        <p>Value is: {{value}}</p>

    {{/each}}

</template>
```

Comment: Edit: fixed a typo: "elementToReturn" was called "loop" in .js.

Comment: Also: simply add underscore with mrt/meteor add underscore